# How do I show that an entire function which is real for all $z\in \mathbb C$ with $Im(z)=0$ or $\pi$ is $2\pi i$ periodic?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I have an entire function $f$ which takes real values on all complex numbers with imaginary parts $0$ or $\pi$. I'm trying to show that $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. I tried using the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but to no avail. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Do you know that if $f(z)$ is real for real $z$ then $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the entire function $\overline{f(\overline z)}-{f(z)}$ is $=0$ for $z\in\Bbb R$, this also holds for $z\in\Bbb C$.
Therefore, $f(a+i\pi)=\overline{f(a-i\pi)}=f(a-i\pi)$.
But then $f(z-\pi i)-f(z+\pi i)$ is entire and $=0$ on $\Bbb R$, hence on $\Bbb C$.